# Default behavior of th table tags

Tags: html, css, materialize

On large screens my table TH is on top but when I run it on mobile devices those THs goes to the left side. Is that the default behavior of TH of tables? I'm using Matrialize css class of 'responsive-table'.

```
  <table class="responsive-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th data-field="id">Name</th>
          <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
          <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Alvin</td>
        <td>Eclair</td>
        <td>$0.87</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alan</td>
        <td>Jellybean</td>
        <td>$3.76</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jonathan</td>
        <td>Lollipop</td>
        <td>$7.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the default behavior when you add a class of `responsive-table`. The documentation states:

> Add class="responsive-table" to the table tag to make the table
>   horizontally scrollable on smaller screen widths.

Get into the habit of checking documentation! I've never used materialize but I found the answer very quickly by searching their website.

Source: [Tables in materialize.css](http://materializecss.com/table.html)

Answer (score 1):

Default behavior will just make your table headings bold but should not make them go to the left.  It is going to the left because you are using a responsive design stylesheet.